# React : How to solve "System" is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I tried to add react-component-async component

Ref: https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-async-component

by using react-cool-starter boilter-palate

Ref: https://github.com/wellyshen/react-cool-starter

Unfortunately, when I rewrite Home Component to by async component with below code.

```
import { asyncComponent } from 'react-async-component';

export default asyncComponent({
  resolve: () => System.import('./home')
});
```

Then rebuilding with webpack, it thrown and error that "System is not defined" as below.

```
Failed to resolve asyncComponent
ReferenceError: System is not defined
at resolve (D:/nodejs/react-cool-starter-master/src/containers/Home/index.js:4:12)
```

Could you please help me how I use "System.import" in global scope?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should install [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) via `npm` and import it into your component file.

```
npm install systemjs
```

*AsyncComponent*

```
import { asyncComponent } from 'react-async-component';
import System from 'systemjs'

export default asyncComponent({
  resolve: () => System.import('./home')
});
```

That might help you.

Comment: It can be one of the solution, but when I take a look at component author use case, he didn't import systemjs at all.

Ref : https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-universally

So I curious how "system.import from that that's use case work.

Answer (score -2):

Just use `import()`. If you are transpiling with Babel, it will understand.